# ARM Template that deploys Subnet and NSG at the same time

Tags: json, azure, terraform, azure-rm-template

There is a current policy (DenySubnetWithoutNSG) in our framework that basically prevents deployment of subnets without an nsg. I am trying to bypass this policy through a custom ARM template below is an idea of what I am working with:

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

Comment: Could you please help us with the code rather than images

Answer (score 0):

Your Policy is to prevent, so it is working as expected and there should be no possibility to bypass ;> Anyway, below ARM creates a Subnet with NSG in one run and it will fit into the policy expecting NSG on Subnet (of course review params and ajust to your need):

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "addressPrefix": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "name": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "vnet": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "nsgId": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
            "apiVersion": "2021-03-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('vnet'), '/', parameters('name'))]",
            "properties": {
                "addressPrefix": "[parameters('addressPrefix')]",
                "delegations": [],
                "networkSecurityGroup": {
                    "id": "[parameters('nsgId')]"
                },
                "privateEndpointNetworkPolicies": "Enabled",
                "privateLinkServiceNetworkPolicies": "Enabled",
                "serviceEndpoints": []
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {
        "subnetId": {
            "type": "String",
            "value": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('vnet'), parameters('name'))]"
        }
    }
}
```